# Найти запись в таблице к каждому слову в записи другой таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две таблицы. В столбце `users` первой таблицы вписывается текстом несколько имен. В другой столбец `user` где каждая запись это имя. Мне надо, что бы каждому имени из столбца `users` находило такое же из таблицы `user` с его айдишником. И можно ли вообще так сделать?

Таблица 1

| id | users |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Max, Ivan |
| 2 | Dima, Sanya, Nikolo |

Таблица 2

| id | user |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Nikolo |
| 2 | Ivan |
| 3 | Dima |
| 4 | Sanya |
| 5 | Max |

Comment: да, можно. читаете первую таблицу построчно, разбиваете на слова, ищете во второй id. Это самый простой вариант

Comment: храните данные нормально, не надо костыли делать. Вместо первой таблицы с именами у вас должна быт таблица `(1,5), (1,2), (2,3), (2,4), (2,1)` сразу. хотя быть может вы и пытаетесь такую создать в данной задаче.

Comment: `ON FIND_IN_SET(user,users)`